# What are the risks of autologous blood injection used to treat a tendinopathy?

Tags: side-effects, tendinopathy, autologous-blood-inject

I wonder what the risks of [autologous blood injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autologous_blood_injection) are when used to treat a tendinopathy (specifically, lateral epicondylitis of the humerus).

I read a unquantified few sources, but ideally I'd like to have quantified risk assessment (e.g., 1% chance of injury to structures near the tendon).

Example:
http://www.sportsmed.net.nz/patient-info/general-rehabilitation/autologous-blood-injections/:

> Pain was one of the main problems reported. In one study of 35 patients, 25 had pain and stiffness after the procedure, which went away within 2 days. Most patients reported that the pain was similar to the pain they had after steroid injection. Other potential complications include infection, injury to structures near the tendon and bruising at the injection site.

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.